# Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE]

Tags: android, xml, react-native, manifest

when I start run the app  am getting below error. Please anyone can you help me to solve this issue.

$ adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d 'hpRN://result'
Error while executing: am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d 'hpRN://result'
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=hpRN://result }
Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW cat=[android.intent.category.BROWSABLE] dat=hpRN://result flg=0x10000000 }

Error while Launching URL

Comment: There is no app on that device that has an activity that supports that `Intent` structure. In particular, `htpRN` does not seem like it is likely to be a supported URL scheme.